# Rep gained not showing on achievements dropdown, but does in rep tab

Tags: discussion, bug, reputation

I was wondering if anyone else is experiencing this. I gained reputation from some upvotes, but **that change is not showing in the achievements dropdown**:

[image]

I checked, and that reputation does appear on the reputation tab of my profile:

[image]

I already waited some time to see if it was due to caching. **Could this be a bug of some kind?**

Comment: Yep, this was reported on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303760/wrong-reputation-calculation)

Comment: @Catija thanks, just saw that Meta Post also :) In my case, this happened only with my TWP rep. My SO rep I gained today is fine (just 12 reps but still)

Comment: @Catija be aware that "MSE" is also a widely used acronym for "mathematics stack exchange." To avoid confusion, I use Meta SE and Math SE respectively.

Comment: @StellaBiderman It's a link... and everyone uses "MSE" to mean Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Catija Actually, the convention is to use mSE for Meta Stack Exchange but it's only required _when it's ambiguous_.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I've been on MSE for years and never seen anyone use that that I know of... but sure. I use MSE for meta, Math for Math.SE... but I rarely refer to the latter.

Comment: I have to agree with @Catija on that terminology. Never heard of MSE being used as Math Stack Exchange. Still discussing that seems tangential to the content of this post, or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Catija [Here's an example](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26740460#26740460) (mod-only because reasons) of MSE being used to mean Math Stack Exchange. It's fairly common.

Comment: Though it used to be rather common, admittedly mSE is not often used any more (survey of TL messages).